# Can forEach be used to increment or decrement by more than 1 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can `forEach` function be used to loop over an array by more than 1? For eg using `for` loop we do it like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<my_arr.length; i+=2) {
    //code
}
```

Comment: "For *each*". Not "For each *except*".

Comment: I guess you could just ```return``` when the index is uneven, effectively skipping that iteration.

Comment: All answers clarified my doubt. I am accepting the first answer as the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. However, it is easy to skip elements by their index:

```js
let my_arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

my_arr.forEach((e, i, a) => {
  if (i % 2 != 0) return;
  console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

No, you can not omit some indices without explicit returning in the callback.

```
array.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (index % 2) return;
    // your code
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just `return` from an incorrect index:

```js
const my_arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

my_arr.forEach((e, i) => {
  if (!(i % 2)) return;
  console.log(e);
});
```